# Error compilacion al instalar un paquete en RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando instalar en RStudio para la version 4.1 el paquete "mclust". Me sale este error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/n618587/OneDrive - Santander Office 365/Documentos/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'cld2' ...
** package 'cld2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cld2'
* removing 'C:/Users/n618587/OneDrive - Santander Office 365/Documentos/R/win-library/4.1/cld2'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Z:/0LT27D~K/0YOA69~Q/2NL0HA~C/AB/Paquetes/cld2_1.2.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido user a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: El paquete `cld2` seguramente código C++ requiere compilarse, para esto necesitas un compilador C++ que viene incluido en  Rtools. Deberás instalar este software para brindarle a R el entorno necesario para resolver la compilación.  La descarga: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/